# How can I infer type from interface with generically typed props

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have setup like this

```
interface IServiceRegistry<T> {
  [id: string]: T;
}


interface ExampleService {
    a: number;
}

interface AnotherExampleService {
    b: string;
}

interface IRegistry {
  exampleService: IServiceRegistry<ExampleService>;
  anotherExampleService: IServiceRegistry<AnotherExampleService>;
}

type GetService<M> = M extends IServiceRegistry<infer X> ? X : never;

function getService<K extends keyof IRegistry>(
  serviceType: K,
  serviceName: string,
): GetService<IRegistry[K]> {
  return registry[serviceType][serviceName];
}

const registry = {} as IRegistry;
```

so then I can the following and have all typing support

```
const s1 = getService('exampleService', 'someName');
// const s1: ExampleService

const s2 = getService('anotherExampleService', 'someName');
// const s2: AnotherExampleService
```

Unfortunately getService function return type `GetService<IRegistry[K]>` doesn't work in this case.

`Type 'ExampleService | AnotherExampleService' is not assignable to type 'GetService<IRegistry[K]>'. Type 'ExampleService' is not assignable to type 'GetService<IRegistry[K]>'.`

How to get proper typing work for `getService` function?

Comment: can you include the definition of `IPlatformRegistry` and specify what is the type of `commonRegistry`?

Comment: My bad, I'm so bad at writing questions here - I haven't updated names properly. IPlatformRegistry should be IRegistry and registry (old commonRegistry) is a container object of type IRegistry. Question updated

Comment: It's completely bizarre tbh. The error disappears when you add a property to `IRegistry` that does not conform to `IServiceRegistry`, eg: `interface Registry { foo: 'bar'; ... }`.

An alternative would be to change function generics to `<K extends keyof IRegistry, Key extends keyof IRegistry[K]>`, and return type to `IRegistry[K][Key] | undefined` because in `getService` you are constrained to use a valid key of `IRegistry` and all registry properties conform to `IServiceRegistry`.

Comment: You should probably just cast to the return type (or even `any`) here. Dynamic lookups in TypeScript are hard to type like this.

Comment: I've got [several workarounds](https://tsplay.dev/mx8Yzm) that give the right typings but I'm still hunting for why the issue happens in the first place.  Meanwhile, OP, could you [edit] the code in your question to be a [mre] so that there are no undefined/undeclared types?  Either remove or define `ExampleService` and `AnotherExampleService` so we are all on the same page.

Comment: I haven't found a canonical issue; I might file one. The problem with `GetService` is that it's a conditional type, and the compiler cannot verify generic conditional types in function bodies; see [ms/TS#33912](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for a related problem. The fix is to switch to indexed accesses, but there's a limitation with using `string` directly, so I'd use `string & keyof IRegistry[K]`, like [this](//tsplay.dev/ND2kjW).  If that fully addresses your question I'll write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing? Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply.

Comment: @jcalz I've tried your workarounds and they indeed work. Thanks so much for spending time on this. I'm going to stick with `string & keyof IRegistry[K]`. This fully addresses the question.

Comment: Okay, I filed [ms/TS#51127](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51127) and I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `GetService<IRegistry[K]>` is that, inside the body of `getService()`, it's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on an unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `K`.  The TypeScript type checker really doesn't know how to do much with such types; it tends to *defer* evaluation of them, leaving them as essentially *opaque*.  The compiler really doesn't know what values might be assignable to `GetService<IRegistry[K]>` and it doesn't try very hard to figure it out.  This is currently a known limitation of TypeScript, and there have been suggestions to do something better, like [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  For now, though, if you want to use types like this, you'll pretty much need to loosen type safety via something like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function getService<K extends keyof IRegistry>(
    serviceType: K,
    serviceName: string,
): GetService<IRegistry[K]> {
    return registry[serviceType][serviceName] as GetService<IRegistry[K]>; // ‍♂️
}
```

---

But you don't need to write `GetService<M>` as a conditional type.  All you're doing is [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the property type for the [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) of `M`.  So instead of

```
type GetService<M> = M extends IServiceRegistry<infer X> ? X : never;
```

you could write

```
type GetService<M extends IServiceRegistry<any>> = M[string];
```

Or we can dispense with it entirely and just use `M[string]` directly.

So that gives us:

```
function getService<K extends keyof IRegistry>(
    serviceType: K,
    serviceName: string,
): IRegistry[K][string] {
    return registry[serviceType][serviceName]; // error!
}
```

**which, unfortunately, still doesn't work**. I'm not 100% sure why this happens; analogous constructs tend to work. After all, I'm indexing into a value of type `IRegistry` with a key of type `K` to get a value of type `IRegistry[K]`, and then indexing into that with a key of type `string` to get a value of type `IRegistry[K][string]`.  But it's not working.  I filed [microsoft/TypeScript#51127](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51127) to find out why, but for now this is some sort of design limitation in TypeScript.

---

Let's work around it.  The easiest way I can see to do that is to change `serviceType` from `string` to `string & keyof IRegistry[K]`. This should be equivalent to `string`, but now the compiler should understand that we're indexing into `IRegistry[K]` with `keyof IRegistry[K]`:

```
function getService<K extends keyof IRegistry>(
    serviceType: K,
    serviceName: string & keyof IRegistry[K],
): IRegistry[K][typeof serviceName] {
    return registry[serviceType][serviceName]; // okay
}
```

Now that compiles without error, hooray!  And you get the behavior you're looking for:

```
const s = getService('exampleService', 'someName');
// const s: ExampleService
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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-gCIECQe9NmkqI0KHQfshPjb5SBRJj2NjcfjCcT1ZLyZTqet6YzmT6IRyxRFbaF7YKRT32H2kC7BTFy4r2Crkw38pqc+Vdfr49yTWaLXNfdbRxAB469+ORBJkAB6M--KBQTxQACEYqDQbk1bxBIt9dJFPTmbpDKZLI7t2vZ8gK-BDiBkrjnKQjlsgABkf7toBEIrqKs6dmkK4cImEAAUe+zuoaxqvJulo7k6koHpR+THlIQaTNMYACEsRIppK7IAORZIEuSjJxwrIJxJCeK646cUqUgXsgjEzCQ-DDHxkpyEAA)